# How to create 8 cell adjacency map for a diagonal enabled A* algorithm with the networkx library

Tags: python, networkx

By default, the `nx.grid_graph(dim)` gives the four nearest neighbours grid graph. Is there a method to get the diagonals as well to create an eight nearest neighbours map or must the diagonals be added separately? If so, how can this be done?

Also, is there a method to weigh the diagonals with a length attribute of `2**0.5 = 1.414` so that pathfinding considers diagonals with the appropriate weighting?

This is the first time I am using `networkx` and I tried to find an answer in the documentation but I could not find any mention for eight cell connectivity or an example of how to weigh differently top/down/left/right neighbour cells from diagonal neighbouring cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Networkx has no built-in functions for it so you should add these edges manually. Fortunately, `networkx.grid_2d` constructs nodes as points with cartesian coordinates. It simplifies our code greatly. Here it is:

```
# Create 4x4 grid graph
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(4,4)
G.nodes

    # Here you can see that nodes are just points with coordinates
    NodeView(((0, 1), (1, 2), (3, 2), (0, 0), (3, 3), (3, 0), (3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (0, 2), (2, 0), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (1, 0), (0, 3)))

# Set all weights to 1
for edge in G.edges:
    G.edges[edge]['weight'] = 1
```

If you have 4 points:

```
0,0    1,0


0,1    1,1
```

you need to create edges from `0,0` to `1,1` and from `1,0` to `0,1`. So we create them with `weight=1.4`:

```
G.add_edges_from([
    ((x, y), (x+1, y+1))
    for x in range(3)
    for y in range(3)
] + [
    ((x+1, y), (x, y+1))
    for x in range(3)
    for y in range(3)
], weight=1.4)
```

and draw the graph:

`nx.draw(G)`

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make this look straight and not stretched? Thank you